# iOS and Mechanical Turk

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I want to develop an iOS app which can upload an image from the device to be processed in an HIT on Amazon Mechanical Turk and the text result can be relayed back to the iOS device.

I know there is no native iOS API for Mechanical Turk, but is there a way to go around that by using something else perhaps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the Amazon API directly from your app, because in that case you would need to distribute your AWS access key & secret with the app. (I'll let you figure out why this would be bad thing)

You need a backend for your app, from where you'd send work items to the Amazon service, and notify the iOS app instance upon completion.